# How do I get a count of comments by querying the database table?

Tags: database

I'm migrating my Drupal forum and trying to export MySQL base as CSV. Among other things, I need to get comment counts.

How can I achieve it?

To be clear, this is what I have up to now:

```
SELECT node.nid, forum.tid, node_revisions.uid, node_revisions.title, node_revisions.body
FROM node, forum, node_revisions
WHERE node.vid=node_revisions.vid AND node_revisions.vid=forum.vid AND type='forum'
```

And I also would like to get comment counts for every node.

To be even more clear, this is what I would like to get.

```
| nid  | taxonomy id | author   | title      |  body       |comments count|
|------|-------------|----------|------------|-------------|--------------|
| 3    | 2           | 1        | Topic 1    | Topic body..|(I need this!)|
| 7    | 3           | 3        | Topic 2    | Topic body..|(I need this!)|
| 2068 | 2           | 287      | Topic 3    | Topic body..|(I need this!)|
| 12738| 4           | 4        | Topic 4    | Topic body..|(I need this!)|
```

The last column is what I need to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 6, the Comment module defines a database table ("node_comment_statistics") that contains the number of comments per node. See [comment_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.install/function/comment_schema/6).

I would use the following query.

```
SELECT node.nid, forum.tid, node_revisions.uid, node_revisions.title, node_revisions.body, node_comment_statistics.comment_count 
FROM node
  INNER JOIN forum ON node_revisions.vid = forum.vid
  INNER JOIN node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid
  INNER JOIN node_comment_statistics ON node.nid = node_comment_statistics.nid
WHERE node.type = 'forum'
```

Comment: Bingo! I thinks this is the right way to get count of comments in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using the following query:

```
SELECT count(comments.cid), node.nid
FROM node
INNER JOIN comments on node.nid = comments.nid
WHERE node.type='forum'
GROUP BY node.nid
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I could retrieve remaining fields by adding more INNER_JOIN clauses.